# How can I solve this third order equation using the ODE45 function?

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, runge-kutta

When I convert the third order ODE into a system of first order ODEs, I got this:

```
x1' = x2;
x2' = x3;
x3' = R1*x1+R2*x2-alpha*x3;
x4' = 1;

where
x4 = t; 
R1 = -0.000001*(1-cos(theta*x4))-theta*sin(theta*x4)+1;
R2 = -(1-cos(theta*x4));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a file, for example, diffeq.m

```
function xdot = diffeq(t, x)
x4 = t;
R1 = -0.000001*(1-cos(theta*x4))-theta*sin(theta*x4)+1;
R2 = -(1-cos(theta*x4));
xdot(1) = x(2);
xdot(2) = x(3);
xdot(3) = R1*x(1)+R2*x(2)-alpha*x(3);

xdot = xdot'; % ODE solver expects a column vector.
```

Then call it using the ODE45 syntax (from here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html?refresh=true).

```
[t,x] = ode45(@diffeq, [tmin tmax], [x1_0, x2_0, x3_0, x4_0]);
```